# Incorrect throughput value in python

Tags: sockets, server, client, file-transfer, throughput

I am writing a python code to find throughput between server and client. It is based on speedtest.net functionality where I am sending a dummy file to calculate the speed. The problem I am facing is unreliable throughput output. I will appreciate your suggestions on the same. Here is the code.

**server.py**

```
import socket

import os

port = 60000
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

print 'Server listening....'

while True:
   conn, addr = s.accept()    
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   data = conn.recv(1024)
   print('Server received', repr(data))

   filename='akki.txt'
   b = os.path.getsize(filename)
   f = open(filename,'rb')
   l = f.read(b)

   while (l):

      conn.send(l)

      l = f.read(b)
   f.close()

   print('Done sending')
   conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
   conn.close()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket
import time
import os

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 60000

t1 = time.time()
s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!")

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    t2 = time.time()
    while True:

        data = s.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break

        f.write(data)
        t3 = time.time()

print data
print 'Total:', t3 - t1
print 'Throughput:', round((1024.0 * 0.001) / (t3 - t1), 3),
print 'K/sec.'
f.close()
print('Successfully received the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Output when sending akki.txt

**Server Output**

```
Server listening....
Got connection from ('10.143.47.165', 60902)
('Server received', "'Hello server!'")
Done sending
```

**Client output**
    file opened

```
Raw timers: 1503350568.11 1503350568.11 1503350568.11
Total: 0.00499987602234
**Throughput: 204.805 K/sec.**
Successfully received the file
connection closed
```

Output for ak.zip ( which is bigger file)

**Client output**
    file opened

```
Total: 0.0499999523163
**Throughput: 20.48 K/sec.**
Successfully received the file
connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: you need to take the file size into consideration.

**More Details**:
Throughput is data/time. Your calculation:

> round((1024.0 * 0.001) / (t3 - t1), 3)

Doesn't take the file size into account. Since sending a large file takes more time, 't3-t1' is bigger so your throughput is smaller (same numerator with larger denominator). Try adding the file size to the formula and you should get much more constant results.

Hope this helps.